# how to stop an ubuntu update overwriting my code changes in ros?

Tags: ros, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sometime i need to change a little in some of the ros packages for my use, e.g. in `navfn` and `move_base`. then comes the new ubuntu update and it overwrites my changes! what is the best workaround for this problem? (ofcourse, i need a solution other than not updateing ;)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11343/how-to-stop-an-ubuntu-update-overwriting-my-code-changes-in-ros?/) by [harmish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1124/harmish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way is to do a local (in `~/ros`, for example) checkout of a the source code for a particular package, and then (as noted above) make sure it appears before `/opt/ros/...` in your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

But this is not going to generalize well, particularly if you want to distribute your code, because then everybody's going to need your patched version of `move_base` (or whatever).

If you're finding bugs, send them to the maintainers. Otherwise, a formal fork is going to be a better choice.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3